# Bullet graph with gradient

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to customize this bullet graph using the last version of highcharts 10.2.1:

[image]

The js-fiddle for a quick code view is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bullet-graph

What I would like to achive is to have the background the the "row" with a gradient color, let's say from red to green, instead of the plot bands, something like this:
[image]

I try to change this code, related to the yAxis and the plotbands:

```
 yAxis: {
            plotBands: [{
                from: 0,
                to: 1,
                color: '#666'
            }, {
                from: 1,
                to: 2,
                color: '#999'
            }, {
                from: 2,
                to: 5,
                color: '#bbb'
            }],
            labels: {
                format: '{value}'
            },
            title: null
        },
```

With this code but it doesn't work, I keep looking in the documentation but I feel lost:

```
  yAxis: {
       color: {
                linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 300],
                stops: [
                    [0, 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'],
                    [0.5, 'rgb(255, 255, 0)'],
                    [1, 'rgb(0, 255, 0)']
                ]
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you will need to apply the gradient to the `yAxis.plotBands`.

**Example:**

```
  yAxis: {
    plotBands: [{
      from: 0,
      to: 300,
      color: {
        linearGradient: [0, 0, 300, 0],
        stops: [
          [0, 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'],
          [0.5, 'rgb(255, 255, 0)'],
          [1, 'rgb(0, 255, 0)']
        ]
      }
    }]
  }
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f1mthv4o/